# Atualizar tabela via procedure/trigger

Tags: postgresql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de tabelas:

```
    CREATE TABLE FORNECEDOR(
      ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
      CNPJ varchar(255),
      ID_FOUR INT
    );

   CREATE TABLE PRE_FORNECEDOR(
     ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
     CNPJ varchar(255),
     ID_FOUR INT
   );
```

Preciso criar trigger/procedure que, após inserção de um novo registro na tabela `FORNECEDOR`, pegue esse mesmo novo registro e faça uma atualização no campo `ID_FOUR`. Esse `ID_FOUR` está presente na tabela `PRE_FORNECEDOR` e consigo localizá-lo pelo campo `CNPJ`, que é comum entre as duas tabelas. Isto posto, tentei a implementação da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE FUNCTION PUBLIC.FNI_FORNECEDOR_HOMOLOGADO() RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE PUBLIC.FORNECEDOR SET ID_FOUR = (
        SELECT PRE.ID_FOUR FROM PRE_FORNECEDOR PRE
        WHERE PRE.CNPJ = NEW.CNPJ
    ) WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER TG_FORNECEDOR_HOMOLOGADO
    AFTER INSERT ON PUBLIC.FORNECEDOR
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE FNI_FORNECEDOR_HOMOLOGADO();
```

Porém recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro ao executar a criação:

```
[42601] ERROR: conflicting or redundant options Posição: 264
```

Já fiz algumas procedures atualizando dados de uma tabela x com o resultado do update/insert de outra tabela y, porém não consegui resolver nesse caso que preciso inserir um registro na tabela X e logo em seguida atualizar essa mesma tupla.
Casos teste:

```
    INSERT INTO PRE_FORNECEDOR(ID, CNPJ, ID_FOUR) VALUES (1, '46972782000121', 55);
    --nesse momento a trigger deve ser acionada:
    INSERT INTO FORNECEDOR(ID, CNPJ) VALUES (1, '46972782000121');
```

Comment: acho que ficaria melhor para controlar os passos remover a trigger e por tudo numa procedure

Comment: @RicardoPontual sinceramente não compreendi o que vc quis dizer, mas obrigado por reservar um tempo e me responder.

Comment: eu quis dizer remover a trigger e colocar todos os passos numa única procedure, os inserts e o update :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual mas preciso da trigger, pois ela é gatilho para executar a procedure. Enfim... o problema não é esse e sim o erro de compilação da procedure.

Comment: e qual é a linha que dá erro?

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema, tinha declarado a variável errada, segue script correto:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PUBLIC.FNI_FORNECEDOR_HOMOLOGADO() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $test$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT PRE.ID_FOUR FROM PRE_FORNECEDOR PRE WHERE PRE.CNPJ = NEW.CNPJ) THEN
        UPDATE PUBLIC.FORNECEDOR SET ID_FOUR = (
            SELECT PRE.ID_FOUR FROM PRE_FORNECEDOR PRE
            WHERE PRE.CNPJ = NEW.CNPJ
        ) WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$test$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER TG_FORNECEDOR_HOMOLOGADO
    AFTER INSERT ON PUBLIC.FORNECEDOR
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE FNI_FORNECEDOR_HOMOLOGADO();
```